# How to parse command line argument to non-unit enum with clap?

Tags: rust, enums, clap

I have this enum:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, ValueEnum, Debug)]
pub enum TheAge {
    Adult,
    Age(u8)
}
```

And the cli struct

```
#[derive(Parser)]
#[command(author, version, about, long_about)]
pub struct Cli {
    #[arg(short, long, value_enum)]
    pub age: TheAge
}
```

This fails with the error:

```
error: `#[derive(ValueEnum)]` only supports unit variants. Non-unit variants must be skipped
```

When I remove the `Age(u8)` from the enum, this compiles.

Any tips on how to use an enum that is not unit variants?

Answer (score 3):

`#[derive(ValueEnum)]` does not support non-unit variants, so you can't derive it.

And if you look at the required items it's sort of clear why:

```rust
impl ValueEnum for TheAge {
    fn value_variants() -> &'a [Self] { todo!() }
    fn to_possible_value(&self) -> Option<PossibleValue> { todo!() }
}
```

`value_variants` is supposed to return

> All possible argument values, in display order.

that's not really feasible when "all possible values" includes every single `u8` (even if that's only 257 values total, it still makes a messy UI). There is no way to generically generate all values of a type so you can't `#[derive(ValueEnum)]`, it might make sense to implement it by hand in some cases though (for example when the values are `enum`s with only a few variants).

Instead you can implement `From<&str>` for that struct and it will work:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Debug)]
pub enum TheAge {
    Adult,
    Age(u8)
}

const LEGAL_ADULT_AGE: u8 = 18;
impl From<&str> for TheAge {
    fn from(v: &str) -> TheAge {
        v.parse::<u8>().map_or(TheAge::Adult, |a| {
            if a >= LEGAL_ADULT_AGE {
                TheAge::Adult
            } else {
                TheAge::Age(a)
            }
        })
    }
}

fn main() {
    dbg!(Cli::parse_from(["", "--age", "18"]).age); // and above -> Adult
    dbg!(Cli::parse_from(["", "--age", "17"]).age); // and below -> Age(17)
    dbg!(Cli::parse_from(["", "--age", "anything_else"]).age); // -> Adult
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using rust-analyzer in VSCode I'm able to expand the `ValueEnum` macro into the actual code it will generate if `Age` was just a regular unit variant:

```rust
impl clap::ValueEnum for TheAge {
    fn value_variants<'a>() -> &'a [Self] {
        &[Self::Adult, Self::Age]
    }
    fn to_possible_value<'a>(&self) -> ::std::option::Option<clap::builder::PossibleValue> {
        match self {
            Self::Adult => Some({ clap::builder::PossibleValue::new("adult") }),
            Self::Age => Some({ clap::builder::PossibleValue::new("age") }),
            _ => None,
        }
    }
}
```

So given this we can use this code to handle the fact that we want `Age(u8)`:

```rust
#[derive(Copy, Clone, PartialEq, Eq, PartialOrd, Ord, Debug)]
pub enum TheAge {
    Adult,
    Age(u8),
}

impl clap::ValueEnum for TheAge {
    fn value_variants<'a>() -> &'a [Self] {
        &[TheAge::Adult, TheAge::Age(0)]
    }
    fn to_possible_value<'a>(&self) -> ::std::option::Option<clap::builder::PossibleValue> {
        match self {
            Self::Adult => Some(clap::builder::PossibleValue::new("adult")),
            Self::Age(_) => Some(clap::builder::PossibleValue::new("age")),
        }
    }
}
```

The only tricky bit was figuring out that using `Self::Adult` will give us the error

```
cannot return reference to temporary value
returns a reference to data owned by the current function
```

I'm not really sure why using `TheAge::` rather than `Self::` fixes this, but it seems to work.

Comment: It looks like the `Self` vs `TheAge` bug has been fixed between rust `1.70.0` and `1.76.0`, so both are fine now.